Modifying quadric error metric to account for flat point clusters
I am currently reading an interesting paper where a point cloud is used ot create a mesh by assigning a quadric error metric to points, then use that to create point clusters, then assign to each cluster the minimizer of its total quadric.
In cases where the system is underdetermined, we used SVD decomposition to find a point nonetheless.
This works in many cases, however there is one case where it struggles, if a cluster is flat.

In this image, the green points are all int he same plane, so their quadric error minimizer can be any point on that plane. And as you can see, the SVD solver produces a point far from the cluster.
This is however not wrong, that point is a valid point that minimizes the sum of the quadrics of the cluster points (which is in effect just a weighted distance to the plane).
I have thought of adding an additional per point metric via encoding $(x - P)$ as a homogenous matrix, i.e.:
$
D = \left[\begin{array}{ c | c }
    I & P \\
    \hline
    0 & 1
  \end{array}\right]
$
And thus the square distance to $P$ from any point x is just $x^T D^T D x$. This however feels a bit like a hack and I am worried it will interfere with the important part of the quadric minimization. So I was hoping people could give suggestions for alternatives.
